# Hugo theme submodule marked as dirty, doesn't update

Tags: themes, git-submodules, hugo

I'm using the [Hugo Whiteplain theme](https://github.com/taikii/whiteplain) for a personal site hosted through Netlify. I am following tutorial. When I push/publish on GitHub Desktop, I am told that my git submodule is dirty. As a result, I cannot change the theme's background color.

```
[submodule "themes/whiteplain"]
    path = themes/whiteplain
    url = https://github.com/taikii/whiteplain.git
```

What do I do to regain control of my theme? Can I change the color without dependence on this dirty submodule?

Comment: Please add the error you receive

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to customize a Hugo theme. For instance, you can:

- edit the theme directly and let it drift from the original project,
- create a fork and use it as the theme to be able to pull updates
  from the original theme while developing your own version,
- edit the theme inside the website itself.

This last option means that you do not touch at the theme itself, but instead make a copy of any file you want to edit inside the tree of your website, following the same path structure, and edit that file.

For any element of any of the customization files (layout, css, scss, etc.) that exists both under the tree of your website and under the tree of the theme, Hugo will prioritize the element in the file under the tree of the website.

For any element not present in the tree of your site, Hugo will use what is in the theme tree instead. This means that you do not have to copy the entire theme or even entire files in your site, but only the elements that you want to customize.

If you choose this method and if you set your theme as a submodule following the [Git submodule manual](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules), you will never get into a dirty submodule situation.

#### Example

Let's say you want to edit the background color of your theme and that the variable is defined in a scss file under:

```
your_site
  + themes
    + theme_name
      + assets
        + scss
          _content.scss
```

You need to keep the tree architecture and create a file under:

```
your_site
  + assets
    + scss
      _content.scss
```

You can create a file from scratch, but an easier option is to copy the file from the theme and paste it there. In that file, you can customize the background color (or any other setting) however you like.

#### Note

I have found this way of customizing a theme (which is actually the way advised in the Hugo documentation) to be the simplest.

One situation where this method is not optimal is if you plan to use the same customized version of a theme for several websites. In that case, creating a fork of the original theme makes more sense as you can add your customized theme (your fork) as a submodule of all those websites and your customization is thus portable.